# 'list' object has no attribute 'strip' error even when I select individual string elements?

Tags: python

After reading some similar questions I understand that you cannot .strip() a list of strings, only individual strings.  I have a list statesData that is made of strings, and I want to strip and split each individual element.  I've been able to get it to work by using two lines, but my instructor used one line for an example problem and I'm trying to figure out why I can't get the same result.  What I'm confused about is that I thought that the index location [i] should have selected an individual string element within the list which could be stripped?

```
statesData = ['State,Population,ElectoralVotes,HighwayMiles,SquareMiles\n',
'Alabama,4802982,9,213068,52419.02\n', 'Alaska,721523,3,31618,663267.26\n'] 
#etc

for i in range(len(statesData)):
    statesData[i] = statesData[i].strip().split(',')
```

Comment: This code does not cause that error. You're either running different code, or your IDE is derping. Just restart the IDE and try again.

Comment: Strange. I'll try it again, but I was unable to run it without the error

Comment: What exactly is going on in `#etc`. If you copy and paste this code, it will not throw an error

Comment: all that I mean by that was "etcetera..." because the list is much longer than that.  It turns out that I don't receive an error when I run my entire file in jupyter, but if I run only that cell it gives me that error

Answer (score 0):

```
statesData = ['State,Population,ElectoralVotes,HighwayMiles,SquareMiles\n',
'Alabama,4802982,9,213068,52419.02\n', 'Alaska,721523,3,31618,663267.26\n'] 
#etc


new_statesData = [i.strip().split(',') for i in statesData]
```

List comprehension is one line and easy to understand and very fast.